# Problem with getting client IP address in ASP.NET CORE Web API?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I get server IP Address instead of client IP by using below method in ASP.NET CORE Web API .
Please tell me where I'm going wrong. I have used `ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` in asp mvc before and that has worked correctly.

```
private string DetectIPAddress(HttpRequest request)
{
    var _IP = "RemoteIp:" + request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString() + " - LocalIpAddress:" +
                  request.HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress;
    try
    {
        _IP += " IP.AddressFamily:" + Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[1].ToString();

        _IP += " HostName:" + Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).HostName;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    return _IP;
}
```

Comment: See this doc about forwarded headers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Asp.Net Core Web API` to get Remote Client, IP Address is changed to the previous version of Asp.Net

`Asp.Net Core` introduced a new library for Http request and response.

Require the following namespace to add.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
```

Once, you added `namespace` then just need to add following a line of code for capture the Remote Client IP Address.

```
HttpContext.Features.Get()?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
```

**Note**: When you try to run the application from the local system so above line of code return the result "::1" but it will work once you deploy your application somewhere

Comment: It dose not work.it retuns my server IP.
log ipAddress192.168.160.1

Comment: Please refer this https://gist.github.com/jjxtra/3b240b31a1ed3ad783a7dcdb6df12c36

Comment: I also add ForwardedHeadersOptions in statup.cs and it works correctly.Thanks a lot

Comment: `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` and `HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.RemoteIpAddress` give the same result. The correct answer here is ForwardedHeaders.

Answer (score 4):

Getting the client IP sounds easy but in fact I've tried to get the client IP for many hours until I found [this gist extension method](https://gist.github.com/jjxtra/3b240b31a1ed3ad783a7dcdb6df12c36) in @Voodoo's comment that helped me. I want to make it more prominent and therefore create a separate answer. It works with .NET 5 on AWS fargate likely with some kind of load balancer pass-through where RemoteIpAddress alone does not work.

```
public static class HttpContextExtensions
{
    //https://gist.github.com/jjxtra/3b240b31a1ed3ad783a7dcdb6df12c36

    public static IPAddress GetRemoteIPAddress(this HttpContext context, bool allowForwarded = true)
    {
        if (allowForwarded)
        {
            string header = (context.Request.Headers["CF-Connecting-IP"].FirstOrDefault() ?? context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault());
            if (IPAddress.TryParse(header, out IPAddress ip))
            {
                return ip;
            }
        }
        return context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var ip = HttpContext.GetRemoteIPAddress().ToString();
```

Comment: as usual for SO - the correct answer is the last in the list..

Answer (score 1):

I using this method to get IP in .net core 3.1

```
    public static string GetIPAddress(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]))
        {
            return context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
        }
        return context.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
    }
```

In Startup.cs add this code

```
 app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions() { ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.All });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in your **action method** :

```
string ipAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
```